# Wrong price showing in etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, myetherwallet

Etherscan Showing the Crowdvilla Ownership tokens price 0.8754 bt according to CoinMarketCAp the value is $0.07 This is so confusing. And I faced it the first time. Please, someone, answer me if I was wrong.[image]